# Interactive histogram with a filter (button) on some other variable (ggplot2 and plotly)

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I use the `mtcars` dataset as an example.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

plot <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(mpg), binwidth = 3) 

ggplotly(plot)
```

What I would like to do is to have a filter on, e.g. the `am` variable so I can easily update the plots so the plot only shows the same histograms
but only for only `am==1` etc. So I would like a button on the graph so I can make the filter.

Comment: Do you want a button in the graph or a trigger in your code?

Comment: @ Marco: Yes exactly

Comment: Exactly a button in the graph or exactly a trigger in your code?

Comment: @ Marco: Sorry, a button on the graph.

Comment: @ Marco: Actually I don't quite understand what you mean by a "trigger in the code". I just need the graph to update with a button where I can select which values of the am variable should be included in the graph.

Comment: Why not use Shiny Apps instead?

Comment: @NelsonGon: Yes I think I have to if I want to do this...I am currently trying to learn shiny...

Comment: If `plotly` is what you're thinking of using, you should be able to find ways of adding buttons and slider inputs here https://plot.ly/ggplot2/animations/#add-button-options. This is primarily for animating graphs, but around there there should be helpful points on interactivity.

Comment: @ Andrew: Thanks, it looks great, I will try to see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this works:

```
library(plotly)
mtcars %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~mpg ) %>%
  add_histogram(frame=~am)
```

"frame" creates a slider...

Here is a solution with `shiny`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("cols", label = "Columns", choices = unique(mtcars$cyl), selected = unique(mtcars$cyl)[1] ),
  plotOutput("plot")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    data <- mtcars
    data <- data[data$cyl %in% input$cols,]
    hist(data$mpg)
  })
  

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you David! is it possible to do exactly like this, but instead of slider add checkboxes ( or smth that can let you choose more than 1 input)?

Comment: @yuliaUU. I just saw your reply now. Is your question still relevant?

Comment: Yes, please! I am still curious

Comment: @yuliaUU. I will try to solve it. But just for you information this is a shiny problem and plotly is not enough, well at least this is my conclusion. Also I have seen an online book with shiny called "mastering shiny".

Comment: Yes, i was just curious cause I am working with him reports that are not published. I have coded the way to have interactivity of the shiny without using it, but  there is only couple of issues (eg I now how to do a check list that will update the graph, but at first none of the checkbooks are checked, although the graph shows all data points. But apart from it, everything works well

Comment: @yuliaUU: Se the answer. Can you use this?

Answer (score 0):

@David I think what  @marco means with a trigger in the code is something like:

```
 plot <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(am == 1) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(mpg), binwidth = 3) +
  facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

you can just provide a simple dplyr:filter, before you start creating the plot , this does not give you a button though.

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: @ David Weber: Hi David, sorry no, I need the plot to be interactive.